# Google page: fancy letters

Tags: google-search, google-doodle

I used to see a *fancy* google page with various modifications of image-like letters but
now I see an *ordinary* google page WHY? On what this depends? :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That is the [Google Doodle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Doodle)!

And what it depends on is what Google decide to amuse us with on their search page at any time, usually to commemorate a historical event whose anniversary it is.

They do seem to be less common now. They were daily for some time, but I haven't seen one for a while either.

Comment: That's quite a good explanation ... thank you.